# UIStackViews inside UIStackView giving errors

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, uistackview

I want to place 2 Horizontal UIStackViews inside another Vertical UIStackView. The main stack view is in the contentView of a UITableViewCell. Each of the nested stack views has 2 UIViews. The alignment is set to 'Fill' and distribution is 'Fill Equally'. For the main stack view both of them are set to 'Fill'. All of the UIViews has 2 elements, which are connected with constraints. When I place them in the storyboard I'm getting errors 'Need constraints for: Y position, height'. What am I doing here wrong?

**EDIT**: Also I'm hiding the UIViews depending if they have data from server or no. If both UIViews dont have data, then I hide the whole stackView.

[image: UI]

Comment: Have you tried selecting Main Stack View and then Add Missing Constraints?

Comment: **Never** trust Xcode layout suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> Need constraints for: Y position, height

this means that you place a view ( subviews of the inner stacks ) with no intrinsic content size so make sure to give it a height ( unlike label and button which already have ) and hook properly from top to bottom with their superviews

Answer (score 1):

You are missing vertical constraints for some of your views. Just because the stack view is set to "fill" does not mean the autoconstraints engine will know how tall to make each view. See if you can match the same constraints portrayed in the following screenshot and let me know if that solves your issue; these constraints make the views have equal height.

[image]

Comment: Yes this worked out, but through the code if I hide the FirstStackView i will have height of 0, then the second one will have 0 and again warnings in console and bad UI.